# How to make a button clickable out side onCreateView function in a fragment java

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

[image]Here all my data are set for AutoCompleteTextView.when button Click on any item of text from AutoCompleteTextView then it set on  **private static String s = "Thakurgaon";** and it Changes name. How I can set my button for the clickable button. here is my code -

Comment: code is not visible check again

Comment: post your code here instead of posting a screenshot.

Comment: Please paste your code and not screenshots. Also provide code of `PrayerFragment`. Can u explain your question briefly?

Comment: please check. I attach a screenshot.

Comment: i just want to make my button clickable but it have to out side of onCreateView @Ajeett

Comment: as usually we can use **public void onClick(View v) {} **. i want to use it in fragment

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local variable like you have for the listView at the top
(add the following code just below `private listView lv;`)

```
private AutoCompleteTextView actx;
```

Then below where you define AutoCompleteTextView in OnCreateView, replace

```
final AutoCompleteTextView actx = view.findViewById(R.id.actv);
```

with

```
actx = view.findViewById(R.id.actv);
```

Now, within any function that you want (not just in OnCreateView) you should be able to call

```
actx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // put whatever code you want here
        }
    });
```

You can do this without making it a local variable, you just need to get a reference to the view. But this is the easiest way for a beginner.